# When not using UnifiedInstaller, why is sys.path not populated?

Tags: plone, buildout

When using zc.buildout to install Plone without the UnifiedInstaller, the resulting bin/buildout script has a truncated sys.path.  I am used to seeing pages of eggs listed there, where I now only see these:

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/home/campbell/Plone/repos/bika.uw/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/home/campbell/Plone/repos/bika.uw/eggs/setuptools-15.1-py2.7.egg',
  ]
```

When running bin/zeoserver and bin/zeoclient, everything works as expected (their sys.path is slightly longer, though still truncated), but I use the bin/buildout script to detect current sys.path from within my IDE, and this truncated form makes life a little more difficult for me.

[Edit: Additional and more pertinent question: (how) is it possible to mimic the behaviour of the UnifiedInstaller buildout, and insert all installed eggs into sys.path?]

Fwiw, the buildout.cfg looks like this:

```
[buildout]
extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.4/versions.cfg
versions = versions

zeoserver-address = 8110
zeoclient-address = 8080
user = admin:adminsecret

parts =
    zeoserver
    zeoclient

eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
    bika.lims
    bika.test

develop =
    .
    src/bika.lims

[lxml]
recipe = z3c.recipe.staticlxml
egg = lxml==2.3.6
force = false
static-build = true

[zeoserver]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
zeo-address = ${buildout:zeoserver-address}

[zeoclient]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
zeo-address = ${buildout:zeoserver-address}
http-address = ${buildout:zeoclient-address}
user = ${buildout:user}
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
zeo-client = true
shared-blob = on
http-fast-listen = off

[versions]
zc.buildout=2.3.1
setuptools=15.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure bin/buildout always contained only a couple entries.

It'd be bin/instance or bin/client that would historically contain the list of eggs.

bin/buildout is only used for generating the environment, so it doesn't need all the python packages included in the path there.

bin/clients or bin/instance should set sys.path. On some versions of buildout, I think I've also seen it defined in parts/instance/site.py

Comment: Thank you - for whatever reason the sys.path is not acquiring, this is certainly not it.  So, silly question, but still correct answer :)

Comment: The whole point of buildout is to limit what's on the path to what you need. And the bin/buildout generated by the Universal Installer has two lines for sys.path: one to buildout, one to setuptools.

Comment: I've found that telling pycharm to use "bin/instance" as the "buildout script", gives me all the paths I need.  Thanks for helping clear this up.